# R Plotly: Connecting bars in waterfall chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'd like to create a waterfall chart similar to the one below in plotly with connecting bars between the waterfall segments, and it appears to be possible based on the below.

```
#would like a plot similar to this with connecting bars
library(waterfalls)
library(plotly)
waterfall(.data = data.frame(category = letters[1:5],
                             value = c(100, -20, 10, 20, 110)), 
          calc_total = T,
          fill_by_sign = T)

#appears to be possible
p <- waterfall(.data = data.frame(category = letters[1:5],
                                  value = c(100, -20, 10, 20, 110)), 
               calc_total = T,
               fill_by_sign = T)
ggplotly(p)
```

Looking at the plotly graph it seems as if the letters labels are actually numbers(?). Though I'm not quite sure how to create the bar chart with number indices. Below is my try at getting it right. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

```
library(waterfalls)
library(plotly)

shap <- structure(list(values = c(5.82983875274658, 0, 0, 0, -0.0259701404720545,  -0.103678397834301, -1.02624976634979, 0), 
                       names = structure(1:8, .Label = c("bias", "speciessetosa", "speciesversicolor", "speciesvirginica", "sepal_width", "petal_width", "petal_length", "Ttl. Target Pred"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
                       base = c(0, 5.82983875274658, 5.82983875274658, 5.82983875274658, 5.82983875274658, 5.80386861227453, 5.70019021444023, 0), 
                       positive = c(5.82983875274658, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       negative = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0259701404720545, -0.103678397834301, -1.02624976634979, 0), 
                       shap_total = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.67394044809043), 
                       position = c(2.91491937637329, 5.82983875274658, 5.82983875274658, 5.82983875274658, 5.81685368251055, 5.75202941335738, 5.18706533126533, 2.33697022404522), 
                       text_vals = c("5.83",  "0", "0", "0", "-0.03", "-0.1", "-1.03", "4.67"), row_num = 1:8), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

p <- plotly::plot_ly(shap, y = ~names, x = ~base, type = 'bar', marker = list(color = 'rgba(1,1,1, 0.0)')) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~positive, marker = list(color = 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.7)',
                                         line = list(color = 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 1.0)',
                                                     width = 2))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~negative, marker = list(color = 'rgba(219, 64, 82, 0.7)',
                                         line = list(color = 'rgba(219, 64, 82, 1.0)',
                                                     width = 2))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~shap_total, marker = list(color = 'rgba(55, 128, 191, 0.7)',
                                           line = list(color = 'rgba(55, 128, 191, 1.0)',
                                                       width = 2))) %>%
  layout(title = 'SHAP Value Prediction Contributions',
         xaxis = list(title = "Prediction Contribution"),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         barmode = 'stack',
         showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~text_vals,
                  y = ~names,
                  x = ~position,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  font = list(family = 'Arial',
                              size = 12,
                              color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'),
                  showarrow = FALSE)

p
```